# WP Job Manger change jobs url (NOT slug)

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

I'm using the [WP Job Manager plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/) in my wordpress website. The list of my jobs is currently found on `/jobs` . I would like to have it on `/careers` . The listing of all jobs is not a page so I can't change the url there.

I've found [this](https://wpjobmanager.com/document/tutorial-changing-the-job-slugpermalink/) topic that shows an example on how to change the slug from `/job/titlejob` to `/careers/titlejob`. But it doesn't show how I can change **/jobs** to **/careers**.

In the example they are doing this:

```
function change_job_listing_slug( $args ) {
  $args['rewrite']['slug'] = _x( 'careers', 'Job permalink - resave permalinks after changing this', 'job_manager' );
  return $args;
}

add_filter( 'register_post_type_job_listing', 'change_job_listing_slug' );
```

When I add this to my **functions.php** my job detail pages are found at **/careers/jobtitle**. But the overview is still on **/jobs** . How can I change that?

I also tried to change the jobs translation to careers but this also only works for the single job and not for my overview of jobs.

Comment: Please note that questions regarding 3rd-party plugins are considered [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) within our community. The best place to receive support for such items is the 3rd-party's official support channels. Please review the [ask] section of our [help] to learn more about what questions are on-topic and a good fit at WPD. The question may be brought on-topic by asking it in a more generic, plugin-independent manner. Regardless, I believe I have provided a solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check out the `output()` method in the `includes/admin/class-wp-job-manager-setup.php` file, namely this part:

```
/**
 * Output addons page
 */
public function output() {
    $step = ! empty( $_GET['step'] ) ? absint( $_GET['step'] ) : 1;

    if ( 3 === $step && ! empty( $_POST ) ) {
        $create_pages    = isset( $_POST['wp-job-manager-create-page'] ) ? $_POST['wp-job-manager-create-page'] : array();
        $page_titles     = $_POST['wp-job-manager-page-title'];
        $pages_to_create = array(
            'submit_job_form' => '[submit_job_form]',
            'job_dashboard'   => '[job_dashboard]',
            'jobs'            => '[jobs]'
        );

        foreach ( $pages_to_create as $page => $content ) {
            if ( ! isset( $create_pages[ $page ] ) || empty( $page_titles[ $page ] ) ) {
                continue;
            }
            $this->create_page( sanitize_text_field( $page_titles[ $page ] ), $content, 'job_manager_' . $page . '_page_id' );
        }
    }
```

you can see that it's creating a page, with the `jobs` slug (by default) that contains the `[jobs]` shortcode to list the available jobs.

So you should be able to simply create a page with the `careers` slug, that contains the `[jobs]` shortcode.

Comment: I did that but it's still also available at /jobs and I don't want that. I want a custom page at /jobs ..

Comment: You most likely got a page with the `jobs` slug, because the plugin created that page automatically on activation. You're absolutely sure there's no page with that slug? Did you resave your permalink settings, just in case? @nielsv

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here to help :) If you find this helpful please share the bounty!

**Step 1: The Research**

My first hint was that these parts of the slugs are usually controlled by custom post type settings, thus I combed through the plugin files - finally finding that in the plugins in the file "class-wp-job-manager-post-types.php" inside the "Includes" folder on line 161, it states (1):

```
if ( current_theme_supports( 'job-manager-templates' ) ) {
        $has_archive = _x( 'jobs', 'Post type archive slug - resave permalinks after changing this', 'wp-job-manager' );
    } else {
        $has_archive = false;
    }
```

**Step 2: The Change**

Now the "current_theme_supports" function gives us an important hint - we need to enable something within the currently active theme for things to work out. A bit of Googling and this is how to do it, straight from the documentation for the plugin (2):

```
add_theme_support( 'job-manager-templates' );
```

Simply add this to your theme´s functions.php file. And follow the rest of the instructions in the documentation page referenced above (link below), which include:

- resaving the permalinks after changing the slug
- then adding the custom archives and taxonomy templates
- while I do not have the plugin installed currently this should do the trick

**References:**

- (1) https://github.com/mikejolley/WP-Job-Manager/blob/master/includes/class-wp-job-manager-post-types.php
- (2) https://wpjobmanager.com/document/enabling-full-template-support/

Answer (score 0):

> <sub>**Please Note:** Questions regarding 3rd-party plugins and themes are considered
>   [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here at
>   the WordPress Development SE. The best place to receive support for
>   such items is the 3rd-party's official support channels. Please review
>   the [How to Ask](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) section of our [Help Center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/help) to learn more about what questions are
>   on-topic and a good fit.</sub>

---

That said, I took a glance at the plugin, in particular the file `includes/class-wp-job-manager-post-types.php` where the plugin actually registers the `'job_listing'` post-type. The plugin author supplies the `'register_post_type_job_listing'` filter hook in such a manner that you can alter any and every argument to the custom post-type's registration.

Keeping that in mind, reading [the Codex entry for `register_post_type()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), take note of the `has_archive` argument, which allows you to specify which slug to use for archive pages. The most direct solution, then, should be to update the function in your theme's **`functions.php`** file to something similar to the following:

```
function wpse182946_change_job_listing_slugs( $args ) {
  $args['rewrite']['slug'] = _x( 'career', 'Job CPT slug', 'my_site_identifier' );
  $args['has_archive']     = _x( 'careers', 'Job CPT archive slug', 'my_site_identifier' );

  return $args;
}

add_filter( 'register_post_type_job_listing', 'wpse182946_change_job_listing_slugs' );
```

Manually flush your installation's rewrite rules by saving your permalink settings on the Dashboard in order for the changes to take effect.

If you wished to change the text every (or just a few) place it appears on the site, you should additionally alter the `labels` array argument:

```
function wpse182946_modify_job_listing_cpt( $args ) {
  $singular = 'Career';
  $plural   = 'Careers';

  // Alter URL permalinks/slugs
  $args['rewrite']['slug'] = _x( strtolower( $singular ), 'Job CPT slug', 'my_site_identifier' );
  $args['has_archive']     = _x( strtolower( $plural ), 'Job CPT archive slug', 'my_site_identifier' );

  // Alter CPT labels
  $args['labels']['name']                = $plural;
  $args['labels']['singular_name']       = $singular;
  $args['labels']['menu_name']           = __( $singular . ' Listings', 'my_site_identifier' );
  $args['labels']['all_items']           = __( 'All ' . $plural, 'my_site_identifier' );
  $args['labels']['add_new']             = __( 'Add New', 'my_site_identifier' );
  $args['labels']['add_new_item']        = __( 'Add ' . $singular, 'my_site_identifier' );
  $args['labels']['edit']                = __( 'Edit', 'my_site_identifier' );
  $args['labels']['edit_item']           = __( 'Edit ' . $singular, 'my_site_identifier' );
  $args['labels']['new_item']            = __( 'New ' . $singular, 'my_site_identifier' );
  $args['labels']['view']                = __( 'View ' . $singular, 'my_site_identifier' );
  $args['labels']['view_item']           = __( 'View ' . $singular, 'my_site_identifier' );
  $args['labels']['search_items']        = __( 'Search ' . $plural, 'my_site_identifier' );
  $args['labels']['not_found']           = __( 'No ' . $plural . ' found', 'my_site_identifier' );
  $args['labels']['not_found_in_trash']  = __( 'No ' . $plural . ' found in trash', 'my_site_identifier' );
  $args['labels']['parent']              = __( 'Parent ' . $singular, 'my_site_identifier' );

  return $args;
}

add_filter( 'register_post_type_job_listing', 'wpse182946_modify_job_listing_cpt' );
```